# "react-native link" failing for Android with "no such file or directory"

Tags: android, react-native

I've gotten this with two separate RN native libs that I'm trying to integrate.  There must be some setting that is causing the

```
rnpm-install info Linking react-native-keep-awake android dependency
rnpm-install ERR! Something went wrong while linking. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Me/Projects/project-name/android/app/src/main/java/com/company-name/project-name/MainApplication.java'
Please file an issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues

ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Me/Projects/project-name/android/app/src/main/java/com/company-name/project-name/MainApplication.java'
```

Instead of `com/company-name/project-name/MainApplication.java`, I have `com/project-name/MainApplication.java`.  How can I get `react-native link` to find MainApplication.java in this directory, or how can I change my directory structure to match what RN is trying to find?

Comment: When I had linking issues I had to rm -rf node modules then reinstall with YARN not NPM

Comment: ^ that worked for me

Comment: Does not work for me :(

Answer (score 2):

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

or if using yarn

```
yarn add --dev babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

helps for me